# How to target all nested list items beyond a specific level using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I have a list

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <ul>
     <li> <-- start targeting list items here including children -->
      <ul>
       <li> <-- included -->
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to target all list items starting with the second or third nested list including all children thereafter using jquery

Comment: Make it easy on yourself and add some classes to your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selector = $('ul > li > ul > li > ul li');
```

Comment: haha. Your solution is very simple and limited. If depth of list increased, you should write long string for selecting items.

Comment: @Mohammad yes I agree it's simple and limited to op's exact question. But does not mean not worthy.

Answer (score 1):

The third `li` has three `ul` parents. You need to filter li's using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and in it function check [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) of ul's parent of every `li` to filtering nested li's.

```
$("ul:first li").filter(function(){
    return $(this).parents("ul").length > 2 ? true : false;
}).css("color", "red");
```

```js
$("ul:first li").filter(function(){
  return $(this).parents("ul").length > 2 ? true : false;
}).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>First
  <ul>
   <li>Second
    <ul>
     <li>Third
      <ul>
       <li>Fourth</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```